# Excel Fill range with missing values of an array

Tags: excel, vba

So i am looking to write a macro that would basically select a range, compare the values in the cells with values from say an array and add the missing ones to the end of the range.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. Asking for someone to code something for you isn't an accepted question 

here. If you would edit the question to show what you've researched so far and the code you've attempted to write to 

perform this action, it will be a far better question and receive much better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do not have a code yet since i do not know what approach to take or if even i can use some kind of array in VBA to do this task. Most of the research comes up empty, and i posted the question here as part of that. I do not need a code per say just a tip of where to start. sorry my wording might have been confusing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example using strings:

To get you started, you could use Cells(row#, column#), instead of Range("A1")  and perform loops over the array and loop through the cells by row, comparing each value.  Then adding the values that don't match to a new array, that you will later pass back into the sheet in another loop.

Assuming your values start at Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"). With the following example names:
Sam,
Jim,
Stanly,
Jeff,
Mike,
Jeff,
Toby.

```
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim unMatchedArray() As String

Private Sub ArrayChecker()

    Dim myArray(7) As String
    Dim match As Boolean

    n = 0

    myArray(0) = "Jeff"
    myArray(1) = "Stanly"
    myArray(2) = "Mike"
    myArray(3) = "Sam"
    myArray(4) = "Toby"
    myArray(5) = "Reginald"
    myArray(6) = "Wolfgang"
    myArray(7) = "Manual"

    Call GetLastRow

    For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)

        r = 1
        match = False
        For r = 1 To lastRow
            If myArray(i) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1) Then
                match = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r

        If match = False Then
            ReDim Preserve unMatchedArray(n)
            unMatchedArray(n) = myArray(i)
            n = n + 1
        End If

    Next i

    n = n - 1

    If n > 0 Then
        Call AddToSheet
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub GetLastRow()

    ' checking Range("A1:A65536")
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub

Private Sub AddToSheet()

    Call GetLastRow
    r = lastRow + 1
    i = 0

    For i = 0 To n
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1) = unMatchedArray(i)
        r = r + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```