# Compare list to a table and output new entries using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a total novice when it comes to vba and in need of some assistance. Basically in one sheet I have a table and in another sheet (same workbook) I have a list which is changing daily and I need to update this table accordingly i.e. add and/or remove entries accordingly. Just ideas which I thought I'd start with are:

```
1) Do I need to determine the size of the table/list since it's changing
2) Shall I make use of vlookup combined with a nested loops to compare each cell of the list with each cell of the table?
```

All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is currently very vague. If you provide us with some sample data, along with any code you've tried so far, it would help. Also, this sounds like something that a Pivot Table would be able to do. I'd look into that first and then try VBA if a Pivot Table can't accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered a question very similar to this a few days ago.
[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545714/excel-fill-range-with-missing-values-of-an-array/26546828#26546828)  In this example, it was based on an array.  You could modify this slightly to get your results.

1. Yes, you need to determine the last row of the list you are examining. - GetLastRow (see below)
2. vLoopup isn't as efficient as Match, or Index with Match. You can use worksheetFunction.Match to skip to the first occurance or even see if there are any matches.

**Steps to consider:**

- Determine the last row of the list you are examining. - GetLastRow
  (see below)
- Create an array of the Original List
- Determine last row of Second List
- Perform a loop for each item on the Second sheet
  against each item on the first.  - Loop within Loop, this is where
  you might want    to use Match or something, although I'm not sure
  how much time is    being saved by using the WorksheetFunction, it
  just does the work in    the background.  but it's still doing work
  and similar work to what    you can code.
- Create an array for
  UnMatched items - **using ReDim for your Array** to set it's size one
  larger at a time.
- Add the unmatched items to the original sheet. 
  (see below)

Most of this is the same thing over and over.  Adding items to an array by cycling through cells one at a time. Checking to see if one value = another value.  If so, match= true..  That sort of thing.  Look at the link to see the other example.

To do this, use .Cells, instead of .Range.  The .Cells(row#, Col#) format is perfect for looping.  Just have a variable for the Row# or column# and increment it to loop.  It's effectively the same as clicking DOWN arrow on your sheet.  You can also define formulas with a string.

```
Dim r As Long ' Or Integer although I've read that Long is more efficient.  
r = 4 
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3) = "Hello There C4!"
'Result = Sheet1!C4 = Hello There C4
```

**Example:**  This would be what to run to add your unMatched items to the original list.  You only want to add the ones NOT already there.

```
Private Sub AddToSheet()

    Call GetLastRow
    r = lastRow + 1
    i = 0

    For i = 0 To n
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1) = unMatchedArray(i)
        r = r + 1
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub GetLastRow()

    ' checking Range("A1:A65536")
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```